# Matplotlib artists not pickable unless axes set?

Tags: python, events, text, matplotlib

I put some code in my `FigureCanvas` subclass in order to allow `Text` objects to be dragged with the mouse. Here are the relevant classes:

```
class MyCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):

    def __init__(self):
        super(JBAFigureCanvas, self).__init__(self.figure)
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

        self.draggedArtist = None

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

        self.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.figure.patch.set_alpha(0.0)

        self.mpl_connect("pick_event", self.pck_event)
        self.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.motion_event)
        self.mpl_connect("button_release_event", self.release_event)

    def pck_event(self, event):
        """ Store which text object was picked and were the pick event occurs."""
        if isinstance(event.artist, text.Text):
            self.draggedArtist = event.artist

            self.pick_pos = (event.mouseevent.x, event.mouseevent.y)


    def on_release_event(self, event):
        """ Update text position and redraw"""

        if self.draggedArtist is not None:
            bbox = self.draggedArtist.get_window_extent()
            old_pos = bbox.xmin, bbox.ymin

            canvasLoc = (old_pos[0] + event.x - self.pick_pos[0],
                   old_pos[1] + event.y - self.pick_pos[1])
            new_pos=self.draggedArtist.get_transform().inverted().transform_point(canvasLoc)
            self.draggedArtist.set_position(new_pos)
            self.draggedArtist = None
            self.draw()
```

If I then make some text, like so:

```
axes.text(0.5, 0.5, 'testet', picker = True)
```

the code works fine.

However, if I make some text like so:

```
figure.text(0.5, 0.5, 'test', picker = True)
```

the resulting text object is not pickable. In order for it to be pickable, I need to do this:

```
figure.text(0.5, 0.5, 'test', picker = True, axes = ax)
```

(where `ax` is the axes instance). 
I'm struggling to understand why objects with no set `Axes` cannot be picked? (I thought events occured at the canvas level (i.e. independent of axes/figure)..

Comment: include the piece of the code where you make call to `mpl_connect`

Comment: updated to include the full class definition

Comment: The way mouse call backs get handled is just the way the call-back stack works.  iirc, the the canvas figures out what axes (if any) the mouse event is in and hands the event off to the 'top' axes.  Re-working this is on the (very long) list of things to do, if you would like to help, we would appreciate it.